# Filter fetchRequest based on date and linked data

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have 2 data tables in CoreData

Workout:

```swift
extension Workout {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Workout> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Workout>(entityName: "Workout")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var type: String?
    @NSManaged public var notes: String?
    @NSManaged public var created_at: Date?
    @NSManaged public var updated_at: Date?
    @NSManaged public var sessions: NSSet?
    @NSManaged public var pinned: Bool
}
```

Session:

```swift
extension WorkoutSession {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<WorkoutSession> {
        return NSFetchRequest<WorkoutSession>(entityName: "WorkoutSession")
    }

    @NSManaged public var created_at: Date?
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var reps: Int16
    @NSManaged public var sets: Int16
    @NSManaged public var duration: Int64
    @NSManaged public var updated_at: Date?
    @NSManaged public var measurement: Double
    @NSManaged public var notes: String?
    @NSManaged public var type: Workout?
}
```

I want to create a fetch request that fetches all the workouts that have sessions on a certain day.

What i do now is i fetch all the workouts and sessions seperate.
Let the user select a date.
Filter all the sessions based on that date, map the sessions to return the workouts and make that array unique.
Which works but can be a lot better i guess.

```swift
@FetchRequest(entity: Workout.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]) var fetchedWorkouts: FetchedResults<Workout>
@FetchRequest(entity: WorkoutSession.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "created_at", ascending: true)]) var sessions: FetchedResults<WorkoutSession>

@State private var day = Date()

var filteredList: [WorkoutSession] {
    return sessions.filter { session in
        Calendar.current.isDate(session.created_at ?? Date(), inSameDayAs:day)
    }
}

var filteredWorkouts: [Workout] {
    let sessionsWithType = filteredList.filter { session in
        return session.type != nil
    }
    let uniqueWorkouts = Array(Set(sessionsWithType.map { session in
        return session.type!
    }))
    return uniqueWorkouts.sorted { workoutA, workoutB in
        return workoutA.wrappedName < workoutB.wrappedName
    }
}
```

What i eventually want to achieve is an view where a user can select a day.
The app will then show a list view that is split up into sections for each workout and inside the sections you will see the sessions you did for that workout on that day.
[image: Example of what i already have now]

eg: the sections are seperate views that fetches the sessions for that specific workout for the selected day. so on this main view i only want the workouts that have sessions for that day.

Please let me know you need any more data

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10017

Answer (score 0):

```swift
        self.date = date
        
        var calendar = Calendar.current
        calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
        let startOfDay = calendar.startOfDay(for: date)
        let endOfDay = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startOfDay)!
        
        let workoutPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(sessions, $s, $s.created_at >= %@ AND $s.created_at < %@).@count > 0", argumentArray: [startOfDay,endOfDay])
        self.workoutRequest = FetchRequest<Workout>(
            entity: Workout.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: [
                NSSortDescriptor(key: "created_at", ascending: true)
            ],
            predicate: workoutPredicate
        )
```